# Bamboo equivalent to Jenkins color

Tags: jenkins, bamboo, node.js

I'm currently building out a radiator screen to bridge a few different areas of our CI\CD pipeline, pulling in metrics as well as build statuses. We're also migrating from Jenkins to Bamboo

In Jenkins, when you do a rest call to the ***job/api/json*** it, one of the response fields is a color, which acts as an initial health. Great for colour coding, especially when things go red!

However, as far as I can see, there isn't a bamboo equivalent. The two calls I'm using so far in bamboo are

```
/result/{projectKey}-{buildKey}/{buildNumber : ([0-9]+)|(latest)}

/result/status/{projectKey}-{buildKey}-{buildNumber : ([0-9]+)}
```

Any clues or pointers as to where I can get the info from?

p.s. Writing this app in React \ Node

Answer (score 2):

Bamboo doesn't have a color status like Jenkins per say, but it does have a very similar [build status](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/using-the-bamboo-dashboard-289277289.html) indicated by a circle with a symbol within it. This status is available for both the entire build plan and for an individual build.

[image: Bamboo Build Status]

For your GET request, you will want to use the same [api calls](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-bamboo/REST/6.6.2/#d2e289) that you are using to get the *buildstate* value to get a SUCCESSFUL or FAILED state.

Comment: So as far as you're aware, there isn't a way of getting that build status? I suppose I could try and import the status icons directly, but that's not really what I'm after

Comment: What are you after? The API can give you a success or failed status, do you want the rest of the status's?

Comment: That would be nice